# View not reacting to changes of Published property when its chained from another ObservedObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Below is the SwiftUI view which owns a ViewModel and the logic is if the `viewModel.authenticationService.user` contains a user object then it will show the HomeView, else case will be asked for Login. So initially the `viewModel.authenticationService.user` is nil and user logins successful the user object in no more nil.

**View**

```
struct WelcomeView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel: WelcomeView.Model
    @State private var signInActive: Bool = false
    
    init(viewModel: WelcomeView.Model) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        if viewModel.authenticationService.user != nil {
            HomeView()
        } else { 
            LoginView()
        }
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
extension WelcomeView {
    
    final class Model: ObservableObject {
        
        @ObservedObject var authenticationService: AuthenticationService
        
        init(authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
            self.authenticationService = authenticationService
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationService**

```
final class AuthenticationService: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var user: User?
    private var authenticationStateHandle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init() {
        addListeners()
    }
    
    private func addListeners() {
        if let handle = authenticationStateHandle {
            Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle)
        }
        
        authenticationStateHandle = Auth.auth()
            .addStateDidChangeListener { _, user in
                self.user = user
            }
    }
    
    static func signIn(email: String, password: String, completion: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            Self.signOut()
        }
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

However, when the user object is updated with some value it does not update the View. I am not sure as I am new to reactive way of programming. There is a chain of View -> ViewModel -> Service and the published user property is in the Service class which gets updated successfully once user login.

Do I need to add a listener in the ViewModel which reacts to Service published property? Or is there any direct way for this scenario to work and get the UI Updated?

Comment: I‘m guessing that User is a class and not a struct, right? Due to the fact that classes are reference types, the @published property wrapper wonˋt notice changes within your user object.

Comment: The ObservedObject wrapper does not work in a class. You can get updates using sink and ant cancellable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of scenario where there is a chain from View -> ViewModel -> Services:

`@ObservedObject` does not work on classes. Only works in case of SwiftUI View(structs). So if you want to observe changes on your view model from a service you need to manually listen/subscribe to it.

```
self.element.$value.sink(
                receiveValue: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            )
```

You can also use the `.assign`. Find more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/just/assign(to:on:))